# Is this a young mimosa tree?

Tags: identification

I noticed this growing behind my house in early spring. Since then I've kept an eye out for similar trees and noticed a few on the side of the highway that were much much larger (mine is about 3ft), but looked alike. I found out those are mimosa trees (invasive where I am, US zone 7a), but I'm not totally confident that what's behind my house is the same tree.[image: 3ft tall possible mimosa tree]

Comment: Probably. But if it is, you are not going to want it that close . I would cut it now or move it in fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much looks like a relative (or maybe IS this relative) to the Mimosa Pudica, aka the Sensitive Plant, Shameplant, Zombieplant. I would assume that it is a relative to the mimosa, so yes, this would be a mimosa.
The sensitive plant looks something like this:
[image: Sensitive plant]

Just one question, do the leaves
fold up when it is touched?

Comment: It folds up at night. I've tried touching it and it doesn't seem to respond, but sometimes the top fronds will fold up in high winds.

Comment: Yep, there it is! Because of that information you provided me, I can determine that this plant is a Mimosa. These plants react to touch, weather, and the day-night cycle by folding their leaves.